# Select Max From GroupBy Items

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have viewed many examlples but I can't seem to get the syntax just right. Any help would be appreciated.

I have many rows of the following data:

```
Class Response {
    Int Serial
    Int CodeId
}
```

In a list of Response items, I want to get the serial which has the most codes (I want to get the max Serial count).

```
int maxResponseCount = 
    responses.GroupBy(response => response.Serial)
        .Select(serialCount => new 
            { 
                Count = serialCount.Select(response => response.Serial).Count()                      
            }
        ).Max();
```

I think I'm close but I get a cast error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you want to get count for each `Serial`? Please, provide sample data...

Comment: @MaciejLos Yes, I want to get the max count of each serial. I updated the question as well to clear this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting an anonymous type in your `select` clause and then you are trying to use `Max` on it. Specify the field in your `Max` clause like:

```
.Max(r => r.Count);
```

Or you can directly get `Max` like:

```
int maxResponseCount =
    responses.GroupBy(response => response.Serial)
             .Max(serialCount => 
                  serialCount.Select(response => response.Serial).Count());
```

Comment: I used your second suggestion and it works great. Thanks for your help!